# What are the side effects of a Google Workspace data migration

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

In the admin console of a Google Workspace account, an administrator can use the data migration feature to move workspace B into workspace A.  What are the effects of this if workspace A already has data in it? In particular

1. Is all the existing data in workspace A retained?
2. What happens if there are duplicate records?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Have you already read all the articles listed in [Migrate data from Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/workspacemigrate/topic/9991638)?

Comment: Thank you.  I have read the ones that I consider relevant and could not find an explicit  answer to my question.